# using title attribute of an img as image legend?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use the title attribute content of an img tag to write a legend under the image:

```
<img title="This is my cat's legend" src="pet-cat-eye.jpg"/>
```

must be displayed as bellow :

```
  +--------------+
  |              |
  |     _ _/|    |
  |    \'o.0'    |
  |    =(___)=   |
  |      U U     |
  +--------------+
This is my cat's legend
```

And i'd like to use CSS only.  Is it possible to achieve ?

I've tried some experiment around the `img[title*=legend]` but did not get to be displayed as I would like to...

Comment: There's no way to do this in pure CSS.

Comment: possible with javascript/jquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to **StackOverFlow** !

The image attributes aren't mean to be displayed under the picture.
**Instead** you could use something like a `<figcaption>` under the image declaration to put it under your picture.

*With this in mind, you code your code will kind of look like this :*

```
<figure>
  <img alt="cat picture" src="pet-cat-eye.jpg"/>
  <figcaption>This is my cat's legend</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Let me know if that work !

**For further note** : 
The title attribute is used when you mouse hover a picture as a tooltip.

Comment: `<span>` shouldn't be used for this, we have [`<figure>` and `<figcaption>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) which are designed for this.

Comment: "title isn't really often used on an image" — It is used quite a lot.

Comment: "The alt attribute stand for the case were it's not possible to load the picture" — … so its wildly inapropriate for the purpose the OP intends. `title` is a better fit.

Comment: I think Crawlers don't mind if the caption is in a `<span>` tag, as long as it is after the `<img>` tag and they are both in a container, like a `<div>`

Comment: @xaddict — It's possible to write an HTML document with nothing by `<span>` and CSS. Crawlers won't mind about that either. That doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @quentin Have edited has suggested

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, I'll go and choose the latest <figure>/<figureCaption> solution.